# Mongodb and AWS EC2 security issue

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, flutter, amazon-ec2

I am trying to connect EC2 and mongodb .. But after the connection is made and database creation... I created a collection and saved some values but they are geting deleted after 48 hours and another database is visible stating all your data are backed up and you need to pay to get the data back else data will be leaked

Comment: That sounds like a ransom attack.  See https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/update-how-to-avoid-a-malicious-attack-that-ransoms-your-data

Answer (score 1):

Amazon EC2 ip adresses known by hackers. They are trying to join database servers which has no password protection. Their scripts tries all ip adresses and mongo db port. If has no protection then copy datas, delete datas and put the some message as pay money to us.

At this point, please search how to add authentication to mongo db server.